# Nginx location matches the both subdomain and domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm going to serve a webapp only on my subdomain `admininstration.example.com` but it is accessible from example.com too. This is my nginx config:

```
http {

  server {
    server_name = _;
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    server_name = example.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
      return 404;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name administration.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ppk2.key;

    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /pgadmin4/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
      proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5050/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
}
```

any idea which part of the configuration is wrong?

Comment: No need for `=` in `server_name = example.com;`, simply `server_name example.com;` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `server{}` for your HTTPS on port 443.

The `location / { return 404; }` applies to plain HTTP on port 80, alone. You could e.g.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ppk2.key;

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

BTW, there's no `=` in the syntax of [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name).